# Users location information

Tags: active-directory, office365

I work for a startup that needs to populate a world map with the current users connected to the platform (Microsoft friendly organization). There is a way to know where people are connected? Maybe this is something built-in in the platform or there are some logs with IP addresses that could be used to track it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

IP addresses would be hard to collect. You'd have to pull them from logs on the domain controller they authenticated against, which could be any of the domain controllers (assuming you have more than one). For example: https://itstillworks.com/ip-address-user-active-directory-6160708.html

Are the location-related attributes unusable? Are they not populated, or are the staff constantly on the move?

These are the attributes I'm talking about:

- streetAddress
- l (lower-case L, for the city)
- postalCode
- co (name of the country)

Comment: Location fields are not reliable this is a matter of fact for this org that are constantly redeploying people every month and does not have well-connected processes with HR. Staff is moving all the time around the world. The purpose of tracking them is to create a "safety check" for the security department on where they are deployed at this very moment / where they were logged the last time.

Comment: Thanks for the link, do you think it works on Azure AD?

Comment: I can't say. I have no experience with Azure AD, sorry.